# How to use Calendar in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I want to map time request with the user:

User A -Meeting-> User B

Date-10/01/2014
Time-11:00 AM - 01:00 PM

User A is free at

Date-11/01/2014
Time-09:00 AM - 10:00 AM
Is there any way to use calendar in Neo4j.
Please help.

Comment: Can you store data in UNIXTIME format?

Comment: I'm confused in mapping, My issue is:

Suppose for 24 hours for each day and I want to make n no of Slots according to user say:

09:00 A.M. to 10:00 A.M. (1st Slot)
03:00 P.M. to 05:00 P.M. (2nd Slot)
6:30 P.M. to 07:00 P.M.(3rd Slot)
so on....

For some day user may not want to make it.

Also there are n no of Dates where user can fix the slot, and there are n no of Users to who can Publish the Slot.

So, for this, Is it a good way to make new node per Date for each User or there is some other way where I can create only on and map the Users.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

A common approach in a graph is to model Dates & times as nodes to a level of granularity that suits your use case. Check out [this gist](https://gist.github.com/kbastani/8519557) from Kenny. This approach gives you a path you can traverse. Unfortunately the feature is not built in to Cypher yet. You could create a Diary Event that links to the Start & End time. The diary event node could be the associated with a busy node. You would probably assume if not busy, then free.

hth